# Copy Constructor in c++ not working as expected

Tags: c++, class, oop, copy-constructor

I was trying to make a Complex class which would represent the Complex numbers in c++ but I have encountered an error. The copy constructor seems to be the problem but I am not sure as to what is wrong or why it is wrong. The / operator works well as I return a reference to an object of Complex class. but the * operator does not works when I return an object of Complex class. Please explain this behaviour,

edit: I have used the new operator and a custom copy constructor as it was a requirement of my school to dynamically allocate memory.

here is my code.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{

public:
    double r, i;
    Complex() : r(0), i(0) {}
    Complex(int r, int i)
    {
        this->r = double(r);
        this->i = double(i);
    }
    Complex(double r, int i)
    {
        this->r = r;
        this->i = double(i);
    }
    Complex(int r, double i)
    {
        this->r = double(r);
        this->i = i;
    }
    Complex(double r, double i)
    {
        this->r = r;
        this->i = i;
    }
    Complex(Complex &c)
    {
        cout<<"cpy constructor called"<<endl;
        r = c.r;
        i = c.i;
    }
    void operator()(float r, float i)
    {
        this->r = r;
        this->i = i;
    }
    void operator()(int r, int i)
    {
        this->r = r;
        this->i = i;
    }
    Complex operator+(Complex &c)
    {
        Complex *c1 = new Complex(r + c.r, i + c.i);
        return *c1;
    }
    Complex operator-(Complex &c)
    {
        Complex *c1 = new Complex(r - c.r, i - c.i);
        return *c1;
    }
    Complex operator*(Complex &c)
    {
        Complex *c1 = new Complex(
            r * c.r + (-1) * (i * c.i),
            r * c.i + i * c.r);
        return *c1;
    }
    Complex& operator/(Complex &c)
    {
        float dem;
        Complex num;
        num = (*this) * * (new Complex(c.r,-c.i));
        dem = c.r*c.r + (c.i*c.i);
        Complex *c1 = new Complex(num.r/dem,num.i/dem);
        return *c1;
    }
    operator string()
    {
        string temp, s;
        temp = to_string(r);
        while (true)
        {
            if (temp[temp.length() - 1] == '0')
            {
                temp.pop_back();
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        if (temp[temp.length() - 1] == '.')
            temp.pop_back();
        s += temp;
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            s += '+';
        }
        temp = to_string(i);
        while (true)
        {
            if (temp[temp.length() - 1] == '0')
            {
                temp.pop_back();
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        if (temp[temp.length() - 1] == '.')
            temp.pop_back();
        s += temp;
        s += 'i';
        return s;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Complex c);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Complex c)
{
    out << string(c);
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    Complex c(5, 5);
    Complex d(5,5);
    cout << c/d <<endl;
    cout<< c*d <<endl;
}
```

and this is the error I encounter after this

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:123:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Complex&' from an rvalue of type 'Complex'       
     cout<< c*d <<endl;
            ~^~
test.cpp:31:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Complex::Complex(Complex&)'
     Complex(Complex &c)
     ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:111:10: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Complex)'
 ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Complex c)
```

[This is the image to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRNoB.png)

Comment: BTW, if you change the parameter names in the constructors, you won't need the `this->` syntax.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: Try not using `operator new`.  Perhaps that's your issue.  You don't need to use `operator new` unless you are allocating memory that lasts after exiting a function, like a linked list.  You've got a lot of memory leaks (you need a `delete` for each `new`).

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “does not work” or “encountered an error”. Always state what happens and what you desire instead.

Comment: `Complex operator+(Complex &c) { Complex *c1 = new Complex(r + c.r, i + c.i);` -- I do not know what other computer languages you have used, but C++ does not need to have `new` called to create objects. `Complex operator+(Complex &c) { return Complex(r + c.r, i + c.i); }`

Comment: Also, `Complex` has two members that are simple `double` types.  There is no need for you to introduce a user-defined copy constructor, as the default compiler-generated version works just fine, efficient, and doesn't have the risk of a bug being introduced.  Also, why is `operator /` returning `Complex&` instead of just `Complex`?  But the bottom line is that your `Complex` class, or at least your usage of it, is leaking memory all over the place by using `new`.

Comment: `Complex(Complex &c)` => `Complex(const Complex &c)`. Same for every other reference parameter, unless you need it to be non-const for some specific reason. Also, every single `new` and every single pointer should be removed because every single one of them is a memory leak. Remember that C++ is not Java. If you see yourself doing a `new` and then immediately dereferencing the resulting pointer, that's a Java-trap.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie using a custom copy constructor is a school requirement and the operator which is returning Complex& is working but when returning just Complex it is not working. that is what my question is all about. And the best I can understand from the error is that it has something to with my copy constructor.

Comment: `Complex& operator` This is also an error. Do not return a reference.

Comment: To give a hint to address the question asked: (1) a copy constructor for class `Complex` will normally have a signature `Complex(const Complex &)` i.e. it initialises a copy without changing the original. (2) In *every* constructor, members are normally initalised in the *constructor initialiser list*, and the body of the constructor left empty. (3)  Exceptions to 1 and 2 do exist, but are rare - and your case is not exceptional. There are numerous other problems in your code unrelated to your question - all uses of `new` are bad practice, returning a reference when not needed, etc.

Comment: @YathanshTewatia *and the operator which is returning Complex& is working* -- It is not working as you think it does.  That code is broken in that it leaves a dangling reference to user-allocated memory.  You used `new`, but there is no way to get back the pointer to issue a `delete` call.  As to all of the requirements you say you have, such as dynamically allocating memory when unneccessary, writing copy constructors when there is no need to, etc. -- all of those practices are frowned upon, and it is a shame that C++ courses are teaching these bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the pattern of the code below for your other operators.  Note the operator takes the parameter by `const` ref and returns the result by value:

```
Complex operator+(Complex const &c)
{
   return Complex(r + c.r, i + c.i);
}
```

The copy constructor should also be changed to take it's parameter by `const` ref ie

```
Complex(Complex const &c)
{
  r = c.r;
  i = c.i;
}
```

Comment: this `friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Complex c);` should be `friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Complex const &c);`

Answer (score 1):

The minimal fix is`Complex(Complex &c)` -> `Complex(const Complex &c)`
But then there will remain leaks due to the inappropriate usage of `new` there, after some cleanup:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{

public:
    double r, i;
    Complex(double r, double i) : r(r), i(i) {}
    Complex operator+(Complex c)
    {
        return Complex(r + c.r, i + c.i);
    }
    Complex operator-(Complex c)
    {
        return Complex(r - c.r, i - c.i);
    }
    Complex operator*(Complex c)
    {
        return Complex(
            r * c.r + (-1) * (i * c.i),
            r * c.i + i * c.r);
    }
    Complex operator/(Complex c)
    {
        auto num = Complex (*this) * Complex(c.r,-c.i);
        auto dem = c.r*c.r + (c.i*c.i);
        return Complex(num.r/dem,num.i/dem);
    }
    operator string()
    {
        string temp, s;
        temp = to_string(r);
        while (!temp.empty() && temp.back() == '0')
            temp.pop_back();
        if (!temp.empty() && temp.back() == '.')
            temp.pop_back();
        s += temp;
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            s += '+';
        }
        temp = to_string(i);
        while (!temp.empty() && temp.back() == '0')
            temp.pop_back();
        if (!temp.empty() && temp.back() == '.')
            temp.pop_back();
        s += temp;
        s += 'i';
        return s;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Complex c);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Complex c)
{
    out << string(c);
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    Complex c(5, 5);
    Complex d(5,5);
    cout << c/d <<endl;
    cout<< c*d <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is lack of `const` on your references and members.  The second problem is not using `=default`.  The third problem is too many overloads.  Forth, your `new` use is wrong.  `operstor()` are all wrong. The last problem is your operator strategy.  And don't `use namespace std;`.

```
struct Complex
```

Complex is both default public and basically an aggregate.  I'd use struct

```
{
  double r=0
  double i=0;
```

you can do default initialization in C++ now.

```
 Complex()=default;
```

now this ctor is auto-written, because we initialized the members at declaration.  DRY is "don't repeat yourself"; when easy, don't repeat member names.

```
Complex(double r_in, double i_in):r(r_in),i(i_in){}
```

ctors should construct, not assign, members.

Drop the other 2 arg ctors.  Callers can convert.

```
Complex(Complex const&c)=default;
```

`const` here, and let the compiler write a member-wise copy with `=default`; DRY.

```
Complex(Complex &&c)=default;
Complex& operator=(Complex const&c)=default;
Complex& operator=(Complex &&c)=default;
```

also assignment and moves

Now other operators...

```
Complex& operator+=(Complex const& o)&{
```

implement `a+=b` before `+`.

```
  r+=o.r;
  i+=o.i;
  return *this;
}
```

here we repeat member names; it isn't easy to avoid.

Do the same for `-=` and `*=`

Next,

```
  friend Complex operator+(Complex lhs, Complex const& rhs){
    lhs+=rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
```

this makes a non-member `+`.  It makes a *copy* of its left hand argument by taking it by value, and a const reference to its right hand argument.

We then increment the left hand copy by the right, and return it.

This pattern chans wonderfully in 99% of situations;

```
Complex x=a+b+c
```

becomes

```
Complex x=a;
x+=b;
x+=c;
```

after accounting for moves and elision.

And you get `a+=b;` and `a+b` by writing only one member-wise operation.

Just don't use your `operator()`, they are nonsense.